# How to allow user check only one checkbox list using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, checkbox

I want to handle my checkbox list with powershell.
I want to let user only can select 1 checkbox.
I try `$checkedlistbox.SelectionMode = "One"` but it does not work.

Anyone can give idea please. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Radiobox` control is designed precisely for this purpose so that it allows only option to be selected from a list.

```
$radioBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$radioBox.Checked = $true //Checked
```